# Add text in Javascript

Tags: javascript, text

So I have this script

`search.value = document.getElementById('OptionA').value + " " + document.getElementById('OptionB').value;`

that helps me to do a search on wordpress and changes the search url into something like this: mysite.com/?s=OptionA+OptionB, but I need to have something like this:

mysite.com/?s=OptionA+OptionB&post_type=product.

I've tried to change the script into this:

`search.value = document.getElementById('OptionA').value + " " + document.getElementById('OptionB').value + "&post_type=product";`

but the url comes out like this:

mysite.com/?s=OptionA+OptionB%26post_type%3Dproduct. What do I have to do?

This is the product-searchform.php code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    function choose (el) {
        search = document.getElementById('search_done');
        search.value = document.getElementById('OptionA').value + " " + document.getElementById('OptionB').value + "&post_type=product";
    }
</script>

<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php bloginfo('siteurl'); ?>">

<p>Food</p>
<select name='' id='OptionA' onchange="choose(this);">
  <option value=''selected='selected'>----</option>
  <option value="Sandwich">Sandwich</option>
  <option value="Hamburger">Hamburger</option>
</select> 



<p>Beverage</p>
<select name='' id='OptionB' onchange="choose(this);">
  <option value=''selected='selected'>----</option>
  <option value="Soda">Soda</option>
  <option value="Juice">Juice</option>
</select> 
   <input type="hidden" id="search_done" value="" name="s" />
   <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="">

</form>
```

Comment: Dup/Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/how-to-encode-a-url-in-javascript

Comment: @elclanrs - I think this is the opposite. i.e. "How to disable auto-encoding of urls".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seams like your script encodes the search values after the line you are referring to, thus resulting in your extra part being url encoded as well. Look for a line that says something like `something = encodeURIComponent( search.value )` or `something = encodeURI( search.value )`. You will have to append your extra url data to the `something` variable after is has been encoded.

Comment: Then you will need to post more code. You should make a jsfiddle =)

Comment: Aha! You insert the data into a field that is url-encoded by the browser. Instead of appending to the string just add an extra field to you form. Something like `<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product" />` should do it =)